# -bash: nodetool: command not found

Tags: cassandra, apigee, nodetool

i want to monitor cassandra through cli but as soon as i hit nodetool command it says

```
nodetool command not found
```

cassandra is installed in my host

[image]

here is the cassandra bin path and data

[image]

and here is the configuration directory of Cassandra

[image]

i can say cassandra is properly installed but nodetool is not working
how can i solve this
any kind of suggestion or help would be really helpful

Answer (score 3):

You have a tarball installation of Cassandra (vs packaged installation) so you need to provide the path to the `bin/` directory in order to execute the Cassandra tools. For example:

```
$ /path/to/cassandra_installation/bin/nodetool status
```

You can also configure the `PATH` environment variable on Linux to include Cassandra's `bin/` directory so you don't have to specify the full path every time you run the `nodetool` command. For example:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/cassandra_installation/bin"
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for responding cassandra in installed in my this directory "/opt/apigee/apigee-cassandra/bin" here i tried to run nodepool status but it says command not command

Comment: This isn't really a Cassandra question. It's a Linux question. If you are in the `bin/` directory, you need to run it as `./nodetool status`. I recommend talking to your sysadmin team for pointers. Cheers!